# How is performance going to be if I iterate through an object to get all the properties?

Tags: vb.net

For example, let's say I have a simple class and I created an object for said that...

```
Public Class StackOverflow
    Public Property Questions As String
    Public Property Answers As String
    Public Property Accepted As Integer
    Public Property Boohoo As Boolean
End Class

Dim Noobie As New StackOverflow With {
    .Questions = "How do I  ?",
    .Answers = "Like This",
    .Accepted = 1,
    .Boohoo = True}
```

Let's say I have 1000 labels, each label contains a StackOverflow with its own content. When I mouse over the label, I want to show each of those properties in a popup. To be able to do this, from my search results of the answers on StackOverflow, it seems I have to use Reflection. And according to the other developers on here, using reflection is slow and I should only use it if I have to.

Is there a better way of iterating through the object to get all the information so I can display it, depending on the label that is mouse over?

EDIT: Adding some more details to my post. I am creating a custom map and I am plotting points onto that map. When I create a point, I inherit the class so it can contain some more information. For example...

```
Public Class PinPoint
    Public Property X as Double
    Public Property Y as Double
    Public Property ExtraInfo1 as String
    Public Property ExtraInfo2 as String
End Class
```

And when I create a new point for my map, I would do something like :

```
Dim Pin As New PinPoint With {.X = Xcoord, .Y = Ycoord, .ExtraInfo1 = "Info1", .ExtraInfo2 = "Info2"}
```

And when I mouse over those points...

```
Public Sub PinMouseOver()
Dim rowx As Label
Dim coly As Label

'Create a new Row and Col for the title
TableLayoutPanel1.RowStyles.Add(New RowStyle(SizeType.AutoSize))
TableLayoutPanel1.ColumnStyles.Add(New ColumnStyle(SizeType.AutoSize))
TableLayoutPanel1.RowCount += 1
TableLayoutPanel1.ColumnCount += 1
rowx = New Label With {.Text = "Title: "} : coly = New Label With {.Text = Pin.Title}
TableLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(rowx, 0, TableLayoutPanel1.RowCount - 1)
TableLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(coly, 1, TableLayoutPanel1.ColumnCount - 1)

'And then do the same for all the other properties.
    End Sub
```

Comment: You don't need reflection here. The properties that will be displayed is fixed. Create 1 label for each property and set it one at a time. Reflection is good when you don't know the name of the property you want to access.

Comment: All the answers I searched for all recommend using Reflection. Is there something in VB.NET for something like `For Each Property In Object` ?

Comment: Agreed.  Nothing you've mentioned sounds like anything that might require reflection.  If you can show us more of your code and give us more specifics about what you're trying to accomplish, there's probably a simpler way to do it.

Comment: Let me update my OP in a few minutes with more details about what I'm trying to do

Comment: The part that's not clear is why you think you need to iterate through the properties.  Based on everything you've said, there's no obvious reason why you couldn't just use the properties on the object directly, by their names, as usual.  Why do you need to loop through them dynamically?

Comment: Because when I move my mouse over it, I want to grab all the properties and add them to a TableLayoutPanel. Instead of manually adding each property, I want to loop through and add it because my actual class has 10+ properties.

Comment: I added some more information in my main post, hopefully that clears it up a little

Comment: Well, if it's just for display purposes, then I guess there's little draw-back to using reflection for that.  Generally, for something that happens a single time, per user interaction, like that, the performance difference will be negligible, so that's not a concern.  The only time you'd need to worry about performance would be  if you're doing it over and over again in a loop.  What you're doing is effectively the same as data-binding, which people use quite commonly.

Comment: Yes, I bind the data to the label and whenever the mouse goes over the label, I iterate through all the properties it contains from the class to show it. I can't seem to find something that does that though

Comment: So, the only real concern is code design.  Doing it with reflection gains you the convenience and safety of knowing that any time a property is added, removed, or renamed it will automatically be updated in the UI, without you having to remember to fix that.  The downside is that it's less flexible.  If you want to customize how those properties are displayed in the UI, you can use attributes, but it will get more and more complicated the more you need to customize it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have something which does almost this

```
<Runtime.CompilerServices.Extension>
Public Function AllPropertiesString(instance As Object) As String
    Try
        If instance Is Nothing Then Return ""
        Return String.Join(Environment.NewLine,
                           instance.GetType().
                           GetProperties().
                           Select(Function(pi) $"{pi.Name}{vbTab}{pi.GetValue(instance)}"))
    Catch
        Return ""
    End Try
End Function
```

usage

```
Dim Noobie As New StackOverflow With {
    .Questions = "How do I  ?",
    .Answers = "Like This",
    .Accepted = 1,
    .Boohoo = True}

Dim result = Noobie.AllPropertiesString()

Console.WriteLine(result)
```

output

> Questions How do I  ?
>   
> Answers Like This
>   
> Accepted        1
>   
> Boohoo  True

and you can just format the returned string how you like

Based on your comment, you can return a `Dictionary(Of String, Object)` and manipulate the names and values how you wish.

```
<Runtime.CompilerServices.Extension>
Public Function AllPropertiesDictionary(instance As Object) As Dictionary(Of String, Object)
    Try
        If instance Is Nothing Then Return Nothing
        Return instance.GetType().GetProperties().ToDictionary(Function(pi) pi.Name, Function(pi) pi.GetValue(instance))
    Catch
        Return Nothing
    End Try
End Function
```

Comment: Wow, this is a pretty neat function. Is there a way to loop through the result, or just by simply using `For Each Line` ?

Comment: Actually I can just format it from the function, and edit the function to do whatever I need to as well. Neat ! Thank you for the very helpful piece of code. If this is yours I will be sure to give you credit in my code, although its more of a personal project :)

Comment: @TheNewbie You can loop through the result of the new function I just posted